# Creating a prediction model with non-normal residuals on purpose

Tags: predictive-models, residuals, normality-assumption

I am trying to build a model with non-normal residuals as it is supposed to overestimate rather than underestimate while being as accurate as it can be. So far I have not experienced a scenario where normality of residuals needs to be violated on purpose and a bit stuck.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point out what to look for and possible angles to approach the scenario I've described above.

(edited) I do not have enough data to form a NN based model, so I am looking for a traditional statistical and machine learning model that incorporates non-normal residuals or customizable loss functions in training.

Thank you!

Comment: Your description suggests something about the loss function you are using, which can be used to derive an optimal prediction as a function of the residual distribution. It does not suggest what residual distribution is appropriate. What loss function do you have?

Comment: I am not using any customized loss function. I actually do not have experience with setting up a customized loss function given my experience is limited to traditional statistical methods (LM, RF and so on) which inherently try to minimize balanced residuals (treats overestimation and underestimation equally)

I suppose NN based models would be more appropriate given it allows flexibility with customizing loss function, but I do not have enough data for NN.

Comment: It is the loss function that governs how you treat overestimation vs. underestimation, so you will need to formulate one. Take e.g. asymmetric absolute loss (quantile loss function / tick function), is that perhaps what you need? If so, which quantile would you use? Random forest (RF) is hardly a traditional statistical method, and it can use an asymmetric loss function if you tell it to. Linear models (LM) can also accommodate asymmetric loss; think of quantile regression. Perhaps it does not count as a linear model (I am not sure about that), but its representation looks linear.